# Note Timings with numbers above notes

Tags: piano, notation

I am learning the piece clair de lune on the piano, and I noticed in some measures there are numbers above the notes. I researched about it and I only saw that numbers above notes are fingerings. They would mainly be in between notes and usually are the numbers two and three. When I tried to use them as fingerings they would be very unorthodox and the only thing I noticed was that there would be a beat or two missing from the measure. If anyone has any information that they would like to share, I would be very appreciative.

[image: Debussy_Clair_de_lune]

Comment: Can we get a screenshot of these numbers between notes (or, as I suspect, above tied, already sounding notes)?

Comment: As @Dekkadeci suggests, these are probably duplets (2) and triplets (3): with duplet eighths typically taking up the time usually accorded to three regular eights, and triplet eighths taking up the time usually accorded to two regular eighths.

Comment: In measure 13 there is the number 2:

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sheetmusicnow.com%2Fproducts%2Fclair-de-lune-no-3-from-suite-bergamasque-p311171&psig=AOvVaw34iG6_ZhhodSYnx-0ycaOL&ust=1600109896513000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCLDax4Po5usCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD

Comment: Without a show of what the problem is, we really can't help.

Comment: @BrianTung you should post your comment in the form of an answer.

Comment: @JakeGrossman: I will at some point; I haven't yet had time to look at the music.

Comment: @BrianTung I've added a picture, the edit has to be be approved. But you are right about the duplets.

Comment: Yes: duplets. The two quavers are played in the time of three. Later in the piece there are some quadruplets too. You can read about both of these here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuplet#Compound_meter

Comment: Yep, clearly duplets.